# regroup elements from the column in drawing boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to ask that for the dataframe below, how to combine all As to groupA, and all Bs to groupB from the first column, and then draw two boxplots on a figure for the data?

The dataframe is like this:

```
sample  product1    product2    product3    product4    product5
group A1    1   1   2   0.1 0.2
group A1    3   3   4   0.2 0.5
group A1    2   5   6   0.7 0.6
group A1    7   6   7   0.8 0.7
group A2    6   2   1   0.5 0.2
group A2    7   4   2   0.4 0.4
group A3    8   7   2   0.3 0.5
group A3    9   8   6   0.2 0.3
group A3    5   2   6   0.2 0.2
group A3    6   3   7   0.1 0.1
group B1    6   5   8   0.6 0.9
group B1    2   7   9   0.7 0.7
group B1    3   9   4   0.9 0.8
group B1    1   2   5   0.2 0.6
group B2    5   2   2   0.3 0.5
group B2    7   3   4   0.5 0.5
group B2    8   1   3   0.5 0.4
group B2    9   1   3   0.7 0.3
```

The code only draws each sign in the first column as it is, but I don't know how to combine. Thanks for your help.

```
 pproduct1 = ggplot(data=df,aes(x=factor(sample),y=product1))+
                geom_boxplot()+
                xlab('')+
                ylab('unit(mg)')
show(pproduct1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to match rows with A and B

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(grepl("group A", sample), labels=c("A", "B")), y=product1)) +
                geom_boxplot()+
                xlab('')+
                ylab('unit(mg)')
```

[image]

Or, a more general version for multiple groups as suggested by @ulfelder

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=factor(gsub("group ([A-Z]+).*", "\\1", dat$sample)), y=product1)) +
                geom_boxplot()+
                xlab('')+
                ylab('unit(mg)')
```

Comment: If you want a version that generalizes to more than two groups, you could replace the `grepl()` part with `substr(sample, 7, 7)` . If you did this in a prior step to create a new index variable in dat --- like `dat$index <- substr(dat$sample, 7, 7)` --- you could then just use `x=factor(index)` in the call to ggplot. Or put the `factor()` part in the first step and then use `x=index`.

Comment: @ulfelder or `gsub("group ([A-Z]+).*", "\\1", dat$sample)
` to allow groups to be longer than 1 letter